# tableview array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am making an application of iphone, in which i hav one view name dealsviewcontroller, in this view i have table view in each row i am showing 3 arrays values. now the problem is that i have to shows these arrays values in next view in separate label. if anyone has any solution of this, it would be greatly apreciated. Thanx in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question, specifically what you mean by "the problem is that i have to shows these arrays values in next view in separate label". Perhaps you could show us some of your code (maybe from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?)...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view controller for the next view, something like *DealDetailsViewController*. Then, make sure it has a property dealDetails that can store your data structure, for instance:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) DealDetails *dealDetails;
```

Then in your UITableViewDelegate implementation (probably `DealsViewController`) implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to determine the selected deal and passing it along to an instance of DealDetailsViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // Determine the selected value using indexPath.section and/or indexPath.row

    DealDetails *dealDetails = [myArrayOfDealDetails objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    DealDetailsViewController *dealDetailsCtrl = [[DealDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"DealDetailsViewController" bundle: nil];

    dealsDetailCtrl.dealDetails = dealDetails

    // Assuming you have a navigationController somewhere
    [someNavController pushViewController:dealDetailsCtrl]
}
```

Comment: hi MathieuK, i am using 3 arrays in one row of tableview and i want to  show the all 3 arrays values as per selected row. i have already done with showing one array values but don't know how to show 3 arrays values in separate labels.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I under stand your question, you want the 3 values from three different arrays to show in the row.

To do this you will need to create a new **UITableViewCell** class.
Select a New File in your project, Select Objective-C class and finally select the subclass of  *UITableViewCell*.  Hit the next button and name your *UITableViewCell*.

[alt text http://www.thoughtblog.com/images/UITableViewClass.png](http://www.thoughtblog.com/images/UITableViewClass.png)

For example I have a UITableViewCell Class called RosterTableViewCell.  It has three (3) labels.  In the .h file create 3 UILabels and implement three (3) Properties.

```
@interface RosterTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel *playerName;
    UILabel *jerseyNumber;
    UILabel *position;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *playerName;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *jerseyNumber;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UILabel *position;

-(void)rosterPlayer:(NSString*)player JerseyNumber:(NSString*)jerseyNumber PlayerPosition:(NSString*)playerPosition;

@end
```

Now in the .m file we need to create the UILabels and position them where we want them.

```
@implementation RosterTableViewCell

@synthesize playerName;
@synthesize jerseyNumber;
@synthesize position;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        playerName = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,200,30)];
        [playerName setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [playerName setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:19]];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:playerName];

        jerseyNumber = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,5,40,20)];
        [jerseyNumber setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [jerseyNumber setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:jerseyNumber];

        position = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240,25,40,20)];
        [position setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [position setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16]];
        [[self contentView] addSubview:position];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)rosterPlayer:(NSString*)player JerseyNumber:(NSString*)jerseyNumber PlayerPosition:(NSString*)playerPosition {

    [playerName setText:player];
    [playerName setNeedsDisplay];

    [jerseyNumber setText: jerseyNumber];
    [jerseyNumber setNeedsDisplay];

    [position setText: playerPosition];
    [position setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Now in your code that creates the TableView, you need to create the TableViewCell.  Don't forget to import the class we created above so the compiler can reference it.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    RosterTableViewCell *cell = (RosterTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RosterTableViewCell"];

    if (cell == nil) 
        cell = [[[RosterTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"RosterTableViewCell"] autorelease];

[cell rosterPlayer:[myArrayOfDealDetails objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]     JerseyNumber:[myArrayOfDealDetails2 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] PlayerPosition:[myArrayOfDealDetails3 objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]];

    return cell;
}
```

I used three array sample that you would pass into the rosterPlayer function. It may seem like alot of code but most of it is just positioning.